# Matrices algorithm task

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

I've been given a task and I tried to figure it out but I struggle with it. Any help is very appreciated and welcome. Here's the task.

> It is given a square matrix with N rows. You have to find all the sums
>   of the perimeters which are formed by the elements of every inscribed
>   square having peak with coordinates: row index - first row and column
>   index - respectively the rows with indexes from second to the
>   penultimate one.  Also you have to check if those sums (perimeter of
>   the I, II, III, ... inscribed squres) are monotonous series.

---

**Edit:**

For example:
if N=3
we have 3x3 matrix:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

The inscribed square and for this example also perimeter is composed from those elements:
2-4-6-8 and P=20

for example if we have 4x4 matrix (N=4):

```
1   2   3   4 
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
```

There will be 2 inscribed squares :
I:  2-5-7-10 with P=19
II: 3-6-8-11 with P=28

and so on

---

Here is my draft if that could be in help
[image: my draft]

And here is the code I have created so far:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    #define N 6
    #define M 6

    int main()
    {

        int i, j , arr[N][M];
        int squaresInSquare = 0;
    /*
        cout << "Input the elements of the two dimensional array: \n\n";

        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<M; j++)
            {
                cout << "arr[" << i << "][" << j << "] = ";
                cin >> arr[i][j];
            }
        }



    //Comment these 2 loops if you want speed
    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<M; j++)
            {
                cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
            }
            cout << "\n";
        }
     cout << endl <<endl;
    */


    // The next if-else determines how many inscribed squares we have
    if(N%2==0)
    {
        //N is an even number
        int temp = N;

        while(temp!=2)
        {
            temp -= 2;
            squaresInSquare += temp;
        }
        cout << "The inscribed squares are: " << squaresInSquare;
    }
    else
    {
        //N is an odd number
        int temp = N;

        while(temp!=1)
        {
            temp -= 2;
            squaresInSquare += temp;
        }
        cout << "The inscribed squares are: " << squaresInSquare;
    }



    int arrSums [squaresInSquare]; // this array holds the sums for every inscribed square perimeter
    for(i=0; i<squaresInSquare; i++)
    {
        //here we reset the elements to 0
        arrSums[i] = 0;
    }


    squaresInSquare = 0;


    if(N==1 || N==2)
    {
            cout << "There are no inscribed squares";
            return 0;
    }
    else if(N>=3)
    {
        if(N%2==0)
        {
            //N is an even number
            int temp = N;
            int k = 0;
            int step = 0;
            i=1;
            while(temp!=2)
            {
                temp -= 2;
                squaresInSquare += temp; // squaresInSquare can be: 2; 4+2; 6+4+2 ...     N + (N-2) + ((N-2)-2)


                for(i; i<=N-i; i++)
                {

                    arrSums[k] += arr[i][]

    ??????????????????????????????????????????????


                k++;
                }
                i=i+1;



            }

        }
        else
        {
            //N is an odd number


TODO first the algorithm for even numbers and then correct it for odd

            int temp = N;

            while(temp!=1)
            {
                temp -= 2;
                squaresInSquare += temp;
            }
            cout << "The inscribed squares are:  " << squaresInSquare;
        }


    }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: First, can you get code running that can correctly count the inscribed squares within a 3x3 matrix? Also, why wouldn't N=4 case have 4 inscribed squares?

Comment: I can count the number of inscribed squares for every matrix set - 3x3,4x4... but now I need to find out the elements for the perimeter of every inscribed square and fill in the array that holds those sums.

Comment: I think you should explain the problem better with more example solutions for low N. It's difficult to understand what you're trying to compute.

Comment: Have a look at my draft. If you have 3x3 matrix, there is one possible inscribed square, if you have 4x4 matrix, there are two possible inscribed squares and so on. I have to find the sum of the elements that make the perimeter.                                                          For example 3x3 matrix:I row 3 5 6 II row 4  0 1 III row 3 2 9  The inscribed square perimeter elements are 5-4-1-2 with sum 12

Comment: When I'm asking you to explain more, I'm not asking you to just repeat yourself. I don't understand how N=4 has only 2 "inscribed squares". I can draw 4 "diamonds" inside a 4x4 matrix. What the heck does `I row 3 4 5 II row 4 0 1 III row 3 2 9` mean? How did you get 5, -4, -1, and -2? Also, `5-4-1-2 = -2`, why are you adding up their absolute values?

Comment: I add an example in my question - take a look at it

Comment: When N=5, is there one inscribed square, or three?

Comment: If N=5 there are 4 inscribed squares - 3 small and 1 big

Comment: The first step is to iterate through all *sizes* of inscribed square (e.g. when N=5, the sizes are {1,2}). The second step is to iterate through all inscribed squares, calculating the size and upper vertex of each (e.g. {[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,3]}). The third step is to calculate the vertices of each inscribed square. Which step is giving you trouble?

Comment: Just to remind that an inscribed square can have vertices - from the second element on the first row till the penultimate one (how it is on the draft/picture). What I can is to find out how many inscribed square there are in the matrix. I cannot find a way/algorithm for finding the border elements (for every inscribed square) that determine the perimeter for each one.

Comment: Can you do what I call "step two" in my previous comment?

Comment: I have problem with understanding how to do step two and three. :(

Comment: First question: So N=5 composed of three 1-diamonds: (2,6,8,12); (3,7,9,13); (4,8,10,14); and one 2-diamond: (3,11,15,23) so that the total perimeter is 148? Second question: all diamonds must have a top vertex in the top row?

Comment: In your 4x4 case, I believe there are 4 "inscribed squares", not 2. There are the two you cite, `{2, 5, 7, 10}`, and `{3, 6, 8, 11}`, but there are two immediately below those ones as well - `{6, 11, 14, 9}` and `{7, 12, 15, 10}`...

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the sizes. For each size **s**, the upper vertices of the inscribed squares are **[s+1, ..., N-s]**. For example, when N=7 and s=2, the upper vertices of the inscribed squares (of that size) are [3,4,5].

The next trick is to take diagonal steps in the matrix. When N=7:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
 8  9 10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19 20 21
22 23 24 25 26 27 28
29 30 31 32 33 34 35
36 37 38 39 40 41 42
43 44 45 46 47 48 49
```

from point **17**, you can move down-and-left to **23**, or down-and-right to **25**. Figure out the rule: given N and a starting point **k**, what is the formula for the two points below **k** (one down-and-left, the other down-and-right)?

Once you have those steps, the rest is easy. (*Don't forget to test your code at every step.*)

Comment: `<pre>
For this 7x7 you have
5 small: <br/><br/>
2-8-10-16  
3-9-11-17  
4-10-18-12  
5-11-13-19  
6-12-14-20 

3 larger: 
3-9-11-15-19-23-25-31   
4-10-12-16-20-24-26-32   
5-11-13-17-21-25-27-33 

1-largest: 
4-10-16-22-30-38-46-40-34-28-20-12 

It flashed upon me that what you have suggested but I don't know how to make the algorithm.
</pre>`

Comment: @Combine: I cannot overstate the importance of this: **you must learn to break a large problem into smaller problems, and solve them piecemeal.** How did you calculate those lists in your head? Don't try to describe it perfectly, just give a rough outline: "First I did the squares of size 1, then the squares of size 2, and so on until no larger squares could fit in the matrix." Now you have several several easier problems: how to know when a square is too big, for a given size how to know how many squares there are and where they are, and for a given size and location how to make the list.

Comment: I see @Beta. I'll try it how you said it, to break it on smaller portions.